# using python subprocess to run javaw.exe

Tags: java, python, windows, subprocess

I use javaw.exe in a Windows command prompt and it returns immediately after spawning my Swing java program.

But if I use Python's [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) to do the same thing, it hangs.

```
import subprocess
retval = subprocess.call(['javaw.exe','-jar','myjar.jar',arg1,arg2])
```

What am I doing wrong and why is there this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.call` will wait for the process (javaw) to complete, as it says in the docs:

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

You should probably use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instead.

Check out the docs for [replacing the os.spawn family](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family):

```
pid = os.spawnlp(os.P_NOWAIT, "/bin/mycmd", "mycmd", "myarg")
==>
pid = Popen(["/bin/mycmd", "myarg"]).pid
```

In your case, this is probably

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(["javaw.exe", "-jar", "myjar.jar", arg1, arg2])
```

perhaps adjusted to get the absolute path to `javaw.exe`, or `shell=True`, depending on your mood and needs.

Comment: But javaw.exe completes immediately when I run it from a command prompt... or does it? How does it work in the command prompt?

Comment: It depends on what your jar does. The process may continue running in the background, but Windows is just giving control back to the shell. Have you used Windows Task Manager to look for the running process after you launch from the shell?